# how to speed up query mysql table rows over 60millions?

Tags: mysql

I create a table which entried over 60milion rows.Everytime i query one row,it cost me 2minutes.how to speed up query these data.dudes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJnXN.png)

Comment: Please don't use images. Use text. For next time `show create table` is a better way (compared to `describe`) to do this, as a) allows easy reproduction via copy/paste, b) shows existing indexes clearly. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I'm amused that you've redacted the phone number in the query, but left it in full view in the error message!

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't done Indexing on Phone column then please do it, it make faster
like

```
CREATE INDEX info_phone_index ON Info (phone);
```

Syntax

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

Then run your query,you will get faster results.

Comment: As you are searching on `phone`, `phone` has to be the first element of the index. Forcing index will not help. See [use the index](https://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Comment: thanks,i have run this command in mysql.